# I can see node-express server response but i cannot use it in my angular2 promise service

Tags: node.js, angular, express, typescript, es6-promise

[image][image]I have my object returned from the server response, which i can see in the networks tab response on google chrome dev tools.

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {   
var obj = {
    name: "Thabo",
    age: 23
};
res.json({obj})
};
```

And I have the angular2-typescript service that uses a promise to get the response observable from the server

```
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getMessage(): Promise<any> {
return this.http.get('/map-moving-agents')
           .toPromise()
           .then((res)=> {
             console.log(res.json().data);
             res.json().data;
            })
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error occurred', error); 
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
}
```

I even logged the response on the 'then' of the promise and it logs undefined.

And this is the component that uses the service

```
export class MapMovingAgents implements OnInit{

msg: {};
constructor(private myService: MyService){}

getMessage(): void {
    this.myService.getMessage().then((res) => { this.msg = res;})
     console.log(this.msg);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the network tab with the response?

Comment: i have just added the screenshots

Comment: That is not the network tab

Comment: i have both of them now sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getMessage(): void {
    this.myService.getMessage().then((res) => { this.msg = res;})
     console.log(this.msg);
}
```

will log `undefined` because `getMessage()` function is an `async` function.

Change it to

```
getMessage(): void {
    this.myService.getMessage().then((res) => { 
        this.msg = res;
        console.log(this.msg);
    });         
}
```

And your response doesn't have a `data` field so `res.json().data;` wil be `undefined` return only `res.json()` or `res.json().obj`

Comment: @Teebo how about combining my answer with @SimonH's ? Add the return statement to the `res.json().data` and `console.log` it like mine

Comment: That is exactly what i did

Comment: Hahaha! i really appreciate it bro,yay!

Comment: Oh yes the blurred tick, i just did that, :D but its not green

Comment: @Teebo you clicked it and it didn't turn green? :O

Comment: Yes it first said an error occurred and then when i try again it seems like its disabled and i got a notification saying i've earned a hat

Comment: @Teebo Was there a problem with my answer?

Comment: no!, i thought i can mark both answers as helpful because remember i used both suggestions to work out the issue, i marked back yours since you are the one who really guided me through, thanks, i have another problem when interpolating the instance variable of my component class though, i'll ask a question again

Comment: @Teebo ah, okay :) you can still upvote Simons answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the final value for the rest of your code to use

```
  return this.http.get('/map-moving-agents')
       .toPromise()
       .then((res)=> {
         console.log(res.json().data);
         return res.json().data;    <--------------
        })
       .catch(this.handleError);
}
```